# Laptop taking hours to start even after clean install

Tags: windows, laptop, asus-laptop, laptop-repair

Recently I clean installed windows because its suddenly unbarabely slow it took 12 hours to completely install windows and it is too slow hdd is 100% it is taking 3 hours to start back of the laptop is heating

Comment: What task is running that consumes so much CPU time? After a fresh install, it might be updating Windows. Use Task Manager.

Comment: When you say hard drive is 100% do you mean its 100% OK, or its using 100% resource?  If the latter it sounds like your hdd is stuffed.

Comment: Have you tried turning off indexing?

Comment: Have you performed a `chkdsk /f /r` ?  What did it tell you?  Are there bad sectors on this disk?  Sounds like it to me.  Also, you could boot from a Live Linux USB and test it from there if it is too painful to run from Windows. Just know that NTFS support from Linux is not polished like it is in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The laptop is slow and overheating could be caused by the CPU thermal paste cracking and disintegrating. Do you really want to open up the laptop and try to troubleshoot and fix it yourself? I recommend taking the laptop to a computer shop to get the problem sorted out by an expert.